# Grouping data according to a certain field as title

Tags: mysql

I would like to group data from mysql table and give them titles

Table

```
name    data   date
j        a      x
j        y      x1
j        d      x2
k        q      x11
k        r      x22
k        f      x33
```

so that when i group it shows

```
j       a      x
        y      x1
        d      x2

k       q      x11
        r      x22
        f      x33
```

Comment: Do that in your program logic. SQL is not designed for that

Answer (score 0):

## juergen d is correct, however you can make a start on the formatting using something like this:

```
SET @name = '';

SELECT title,data,date FROM
    (SELECT IF(name <> @name,name,'') title,data,date, @name := name FROM mytable ORDER BY name,date) sub1;
```

However you would still need to filter out the column names (some sql links have options for this).

Note that the ORDER BY above may not be what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
 SELECT IF(@a=name, "", @a:=name) name, data, date FROM table ORDER BY table.name;
```